# Haskell: install hsc2hs

Tags: haskell

When I try to install hsc2hs with the command

> cabal install hsc2hs

the following error was returned:

```
Main.hs:14:0:
     fatal error: ../../includes/ghcconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
World file is already up to date.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
hsc2hs-0.67.20120610 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Answer (score 7):

`hsc2hs` is distributed together with GHC.

If you for some reason want to build a newer or modified version, you'll have to build it together with GHC itself.